# Printing Objective-C method implementation at runtime

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to print/log the implementation of a certain class method at runtime to the console screen? I am assuming the log will be in assembly which is fine by me.

Comment: Are you looking for this? `NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);`

Comment: No that's the method name, not it's internal implementation.

Comment: Yes, thought so.. Good luck.

Comment: You want to print the code?

Comment: Interesting question. I frankly don't know whether it's possible.

Comment: You can get the raw byte code pretty easily. But perhaps you can tell us why you are trying to do this.

Comment: @MikeWeller *byte code* is a term in java land. Do you mean raw bytes (of machine code)?

Comment: @MikeWeller Why I need this is very complex. There is an Apple framework class called UIClassSwapper that has a method called initWithCoder that also happens to get swizzled at runtime by IB. I need to figure out how the new swizzled implementation looks like.

Comment: Step through the ASM with the lldb debugger.

Comment: @Tarek If you write code that is reliant upon such a particular implementation detail, you are guaranteed to get burned when that implementation changes in the future.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @bbum I am trying to understand what UIClassSwapper does and the functions its methods are performing.

Comment: @Tarek Sure-- a great thing to do;  my point was merely a warning that relying on the specifics of whatever you discover is a bad idea.  UIClassSwapper is an internal implementation detail of the UIKit;  it isn't even a public class and, thus, it may not even exist in some future release of the framework.

Comment: @bbum While I fully agree to your point there's another side of the coin. Often it's difficult to fully understand the thinking behind a public API and its architecture. There are scenarios where it's utterly helpful to look at what actually happens in some framework. This does not necessarily mean to depend upon the discovered (reverse-engeneered) behavior but only to better understand what would be the intended use of some mechanism. As brilliant as Apple's documentation usually is, sometimes it just does not cover every aspect or use case of some API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add a breakpoint at the start of the line, step through line by line and call "disassemble" in the debugger:

One line of my code (with private information replaced) for example produced this:

```
-(void) method
{
    __weak typeof(self) selfReference = self; // <-- This call was disassembled.
    ...
```

---

```
Project`-[Class method] + 32 at Class.m:176:
-> 0x9c5cc:  ldr    r1, [sp, #304]
0x9c5ce:  add    r0, sp, #296
0x9c5d0:  blx    0x33abec                  ; symbol stub for: objc_initWeak
0x9c5d4:  ldr    r1, [sp, #304]
```

---

### Edit

I can't verify it's working perfectly since I'm not too handy with assembly, but you can use the debugger (Clang I'm using) to just call

```
disassemble -n methodName
```

This claims to

> Disassemble entire contents of the given function name.

NB: I did this with a breakpoint at the start of the method I was using to test

Try creating a symbolic breakpoint to stop at the method in question:

[image]

Comment: Thanks James, but I don't have access to the code implementation of "method" in order to place the breakpoint, which is why I am interested in logging it at runtime in the first place.

Comment: Just a pointer, I'm not sure it will actually be useful: symbolic breakpoints may come in handy.

Comment: I just tried this with a breakpoint in an arbitrary file. I could still `disassemble -n method`. It did find the right method, but I don't know if it was guaranteed to.